# Developing API with nodejs and typescript, I get an error `Property 'query' does not exists on type typeof in connectio.ts

Tags: node.js, typescript

```
public getAll(req:Request,res:Response,next:NextFunction) {
    connection.query('SELECT C.customername, E.estimatedate, E.expirydate, E.customernotes, E.ORGID FROM ESTIMATES E, CUSTOMERS C   WHERE E.ORGID = C.ORGID and E.contactid=C.id', function (error:any, results:any) {
    if (error) throw error;
    return res.send(JSON.stringify(results));
});
```

Comment: [How do I ask a **good** question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: all i can see is a node js method, can you be more specific

Comment: What is `connection` stands for?